# how do we add blur effect into a view using android studio

Tags: android

i did some research about it and got somethings like Bitmap, getting View then transforming it into a blurred version of it then again adding it to the original; view , all this approach seems too hacky  and almost whatever i founded is more than 2 or 3 years old solutions which are now not compatible with the new apis is there's any more clean way for it or any approach which is supportable for the new latest apis if yes then please let me know  ??

Answer (score 0):

You have many solutions :

- use a library like this one : https://github.com/Manabu-GT/EtsyBlur
- use a example code which seems not too dirty : https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript
- use photoshop, if it is a drawable pre-blur it and add it in your project

others possibilities here : https://android-arsenal.com/tag/176

Comment: hey @maxime firstly thanks  for helping ,  i already tried the  https://android-arsenal.com/tag/176 and it gave me some compiling errors and i was not able to figure out why it happened but let me try the other solutions that you provided

Comment: ok. The example code seems good with renderscript. Keep me informed please :)

Comment: hey in this tutorial do i need to create a class ? https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript

Comment: i just moved from developing for iOS to android thats why this things seems totally new to me  :)

Comment: BlurBuilder is a class yes : "public class BlurBuilder {" is a class declaration

Comment: sorry for the answer time. Others are already created : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur.html   --   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html   --   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100725/discussion-between-montana-bucks-and-maximejannin).